# direct image proof $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subseteq D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f\colon A \rightarrow B$ is a function, and $C \subseteq A$ and $D \subseteq B$ prove that $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subseteq D$

I got this
let $z\in  f(f^{-1}(D)) \Rightarrow (\exists x)(x \in f^{-1}(D)$  and  $z=f(x))$
$ \Rightarrow (\exists x)(f(x)\in D$  and $z=f(x))$
$ \Rightarrow (\exists x)(z\in D$  and $z=f(x))$
I do not know if I am okay or not, and as well I do not know how to conclude

Comment: What do you need $C\subseteq A$ for?

Comment: that is for another proof

Comment: Your proof is correct, although you could rewrite and shorten it a bit. Be aware, that $D\subseteq B$ does not mean $D\subseteq f(A)=\operatorname{img}(f)$, therefore the correct generalization of this lemma is $f(f^{-1}(D))=D\cap f(A)$, not $f(f^{-1}(D))=D$. Ironically, I just made this exact mistake yesterday (https://bit.ly/3u7kkUV).

Comment: Will it be equal to D for bijective f? Just curious. Or is there any other condition?

Comment: You have pretty much done it all.  I'd use natural language rather than quantifiers to make it easier to follow.  If $z \in f(\f^{-1}D)$ then $z= f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}(D)$.  And if $x\in f^{-1}(D)$ then $f(x) \in D$.  But we stated $z = f(x)$ so $z \in D$.  Therefore $f(f^{-1}(D) \subset D$.  That's all.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Surjective $f$ is enough, because then $f(A)=B$.

Answer (score 3):

It might help for you to define the sets $f(f^{-1}(D))$ and $f^{-1}(D)$ before you start; for me, at least, this makes the proof easier. It also saves the writing you need to do:

$$f(f^{-1}(D))=\{f(x):x \in f^{-1}(D)\}$$
$$f^{-1}(D)=\{a \in A:f(a) \in D \}$$

Now you start the proof. Suppose $z \in f(f^{-1}(D))$. Then there exists $x \in f^{-1}(D)$ such that $f(x)=z$. But if $x \in f^{-1}(D)$, then $z=f(x)\in D$. So $f(f^{-1}(D)) \subseteq D$, and this is what we had to prove.

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove it by contradiction.

Suppose otherwise that $y\in f(f^{-1}(D))$ and $y\not\in D$. According to the definitions involved, we get
\begin{align*}
y\in f(f^{-1}(D)) & \Rightarrow (\exists x\in f^{-1}(D))(y = f(x))
\end{align*}

But we also know that $x\in f^{-1}(D)$ iff $f(x)\in D$.

Hence we obtain a contradiction and the desired result holds.

Hopefully this helps!